# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rows')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

Trying to use Express JS with React app and PostgreSQL DB for first time, I am following this [tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/getting-started-with-postgres-in-your-react-app/), but editing slightly for my need (recipe storage). I am currently getting this error and not sure why...

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rows')
    at /Users/xx/Desktop/Programming/recipes/recipes/backend/node_postgres/recipe_model.js:16:23
    at Query.callback (/Users/xx/Desktop/Programming/recipes/recipes/backend/node_postgres/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:415:18)
    at Query.handleError (/Users/xx/Desktop/Programming/recipes/recipes/backend/node_postgres/node_modules/pg/lib/query.js:128:19)
    at Client._handleErrorMessage (/Users/xx/Desktop/Programming/recipes/recipes/backend/node_postgres/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:335:17)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at /Users/xx/Desktop/Programming/recipes/recipes/backend/node_postgres/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:114:12
    at Parser.parse (/Users/xx/Desktop/Programming/recipes/recipes/backend/node_postgres/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:40:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/xx/Desktop/Programming/recipes/recipes/backend/node_postgres/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
```

The relevant code from `recipe_model.js`

```
const getRecipe = () => {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM recipes ORDER BY id ASC', (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error)
      }
      resolve(results.rows)
    })
  })
}
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: try console logging the results and see if the rows property existing or not, or results itself containing actual data you need

Comment: Where would I do this in the function? Currently it returns undefined

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and resolved it by incorporating async and await alongside improved error handling. Here's an adjusted version of the code snippet that might help:

```
const getRecipe = async () => {
  try {
    const results = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM recipes ORDER BY id ASC');
    return results.rows;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Encountered an error while executing the query:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

You can try replacing your existing code with this snippet. This modification could potentially help resolve the issue you're facing with the 'TypeError'.